# Необработанные исключения в других потоках C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, исключения

Вспомнил, что Рихтер писал о том, что `UnhandledException` прерывает поток, в котором оно произошло. Попробовал применить это для эксперимента. Написал вот такой код:

```
class Program
{
    static void ThrowException(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
            Console.Write("1");//Я знаю, что компилятор опустит эту строчку :D
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------------Exception was throwen.");
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Are you ready for Tasks?");
        Task.Run(() => ThrowException(null));

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Tasks OK");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);


        Console.WriteLine("Are you ready for Threads?");
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => ThrowException(null));
        thread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Threads OK");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);


        Console.WriteLine("Are you ready for ThreadPool?");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThrowException);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadPool OK");


        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

С `Task` всё работает как задумано, а вот после этой "магии" с `Thread` приложение останавливается. Я погуглил и всё равно не понимаю, ведь в [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads) написано

> If any of these exceptions are unhandled in threads created by the common language runtime, the exception terminates the thread, but the common language runtime does not allow the exception to proceed further.

Почему приложение закрывается?

Comment: запустил. У меня ничего не останавливается, программа отрабатывает до конца.

Comment: @tym32167, становится всё интереснее. У меня оно вылетает в районе 39 строчки. А на каком .NET Framework запускалась программа? У меня 4.6.1

Comment: 39 строчка - это `Thread.Sleep(1000);`, что там может вылететь? Я в линкупаде запускал, фреймворк у меня 4.5.1

Comment: @tym32167, в районе это строчки, просто первый поток успевает дойти до этой строки иногда, пока исключение выбрасывается. Я без понятия почему программа прерывается, хотя по логике должно быть так как у вас.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Unhandled exception` прерывает выполнение кода во всем `App Domain`.
В случае с `Task.Run`, исключение не является необработанным, вы можете в этом убедится сами, поменяв код:

```
Console.WriteLine("Are you ready for Tasks?");
var result = Task.Run(() => ThrowException(null));

Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Tasks OK");
Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + result.Exception); // здесь AggregateException
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Вы увидите экземпляр `AggregateException`, а внутри которого, ваш оригинальный `Exception`. Это значит, что это исключение было перехвачено, а значит, оно не положило домен.

В случае с `Thread` или `ThreadPool`, никто не ловит исключение, а значит оно крашит домен приложений.

В вашей цитате с [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads) подразумевают только 3 вида исключений: `ThreadAbortException`, `AppDomainUnloadedException`, и какие-то внутренние. Например, если вы вызываете `Thread.Abort()`, то даже если никто не ловит это исключение, то домен приложения не крашится (иначе какой смысл прерывать поток). Ко всем другим это правило не применяется.

Comment: Но как тогда у @tym32167 код выполнился до конца?

Comment: похоже на правду. Линкупад возможно сам где то что то перехватывает, потому не крашится. Скопилированный файлик висит какое то время, потом падает.

Comment: @Zergatul, Спасибо, теперь я знаю больше :D